# New line in three part expression graphic title in R

Tags: r, title, graphic

I have been trying to add a new line in a graphic title but unfortunately I am not able to do it. I am using the following code:

```
numcases <- 100000                            
min <- 0                                    
max <- 6
x <- round(runif(numcases,min,max)+.5)+round(runif(numcases,min,max)+.5)
png('papiri.png', units= "mm", width = 168, height = 168, res = 600)
par(mfrow=c(2,1))                        
hist(x,breaks=seq(1.5,12.5), main=NULL)
title(main=expression(paste('Papiri pu papi pipiri papiri pepiri pupiri pir papi pupiri \npapiri pup pirip ', italic('Papiri pupiri'), ' pipiri')))
dev.off()
```

But it gets like this:

[Graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9KHY.png)

I would like all the text to stay centralized. Could someone please help?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Could do it using atop:

```
hist(x, breaks = seq(1.5,12.5), main = expression(atop(Papiri~pu~papi~pipiri~papiri~pepiri~pupiri~pir~papi~pupiri, apiri~pup~pirip~italic(Papiri~pupiri)~pipiri)))
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the standard approach in base graphics is to use mtext,

```
par(mar=c(1,1,5,1))
plot.new()
box()
titles <- list("first line", expression(alpha*beta), ~italic(third~line))
invisible(mapply(mtext, text = titles, line = seq_along(titles)))
```

[image]